# ファイルが存在するのにFileNotFoundErrorが出ます

Tags: python, python3

FileNotFoundError　が出ます。
views.pyに

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
f.close()
```

と書きました。このコードを実行した時に、

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'

とエラーが出ました。
しかし、views.pyと同じ階層にtest.txtはあり、なぜFileNotFoundErrorが出るのかわかりません。'test.txt'を'./test.txt'に変えても、同じエラーが出ます。
なぜエラーが出るのでしょうか？どのようにエラーを直せるでしょうか？

Comment: コードはどのように実行しましたか？ また、その際のカレントディレクトリはどこでしたか？

Comment: そのファイルはもしかして、test.txt.txtになってたりしているか、アクセス禁止ファイルとして属性が設定されていたりするのかも？名前だけ見れば出来合いのファイルと思いますからそれはなさそうですが。

Answer (score 4):

`test.txt`が問題なく存在するなら、`views.py`を`views.py`があるディレクトリ以外から実行しているように見受けられます。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import chdir

chdir("/path/to/") # views.py's direcotory
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
f.close()

exit(0)
```

という感じで`chdir`を使うことで`open`を実行する際のディレクトリを指定することができます。

もちろん、[わわい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/27481/%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8f%e3%81%84)さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/42864/25936)にあるように`open`に対して`test.txt`のフルパスを指定してもいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ファイル名はフルパスで指定する必要があります

> views.pyと同じ階層にtest.txtはあり、

カレントディレクトリはソースファイルの場所にはありません

Comment: 「python カレントディレクトリ」でぐぐってみればよろしいかと