# FileNotFoundErrorの解決方法

Tags: python

最近pythonの勉強を始めた初心者です。
csvファイルやxlsxファイルの読み書きを行なっています。
その過程で、本にあった以下コードを入力するとFileNotFoundErrorが出ました。
csvファイルは練習用に自作したファイルですので、存在するものです。

```
import csv
with open("book1.csv")as file:
    rows=csv.reader(file)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

これでFileNotFoundErrorが出てしまいました。
ご教示お願いします。

Comment: [ファイルが存在するのにFileNotFoundErrorが出ます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42850/)

Comment: Python実行中のディレクトリはどこでしょうか？ `import os; os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 1):

コードを保存しているフォルダと同じフォルダにcsvファイルを置けばいいと思います。